# Почему удаляется объект из массива Python

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Решаю [вот эту кату](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52a382ee44408cea2500074c/train/python) на codewars. Задание вкратце: посчитать определитель квадратной матрицы произвольного размера. Собственно, мое решение:

```
def determinant(matrix):
    print('Matrix: ',matrix)
    
    def minor(i,m):
        #здесь специально копирую переданную матрицу, чтобы с ней ничего не случилось
        major=m.copy()
        print('Major: ',major)
        major.pop(0)
        for row in major:
            row.pop(i)
        print('Minor: ',major)
        return major
    
    if len(matrix)==1:
        print('Det: ',matrix[0][0])
        return matrix[0][0]
    
    sum=0
    
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        print('Iter: ',j)
        print('Before matrix: ',matrix)
        sum+=((-1)**j)*matrix[0][j]*determinant(minor(j,matrix))#вот после этой строки удаляется элемент
        print('After matrix: ',matrix)
        
    print('Det: ',sum)
    return sum
```

и вот что получаю в логах:

```
Matrix:  [[1, 3], [2, 5]]
Iter:  0
Before matrix:  [[1, 3], [2, 5]]
Major:  [[1, 3], [2, 5]]
Minor:  [[5]]
Matrix:  [[5]]
Det:  5
After matrix:  [[1, 3], [5]]
Iter:  1
Before matrix:  [[1, 3], [5]]
Major:  [[1, 3], [5]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
line 9, in minor
    row.pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

То есть, в итоге, на первой же итерации после строки `sum+=((-1)**j)*matrix[0][j]*determinant(minor(j,matrix))` у меня матрица `[[1,3],[2,5]]` чудесным образом превращается в `[[1,3],[5]]`, при том, что внутри функции `minor` я специально работаю с копией. Кто-нибудь может объяснить, как это происходит?

Comment: `.copy()` - это "мелкая" копия, копируется только верхний слой ссылок, а внутренние ссылки остаются те же самые. Попробуйте использовать `from copy import deepcopy`

Comment: @CrazyElf, Спасибо за пояснение! Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данной ситуации, альтернативой будет создание нового массива, с копиями вложенных массивов типа ```[x.copy() for x in m]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо @CrazyElf за подсказку. Действительно, в определении функции `minor` попытка не изменить передаваемый массив `m` копированием `major=m.copy()` дает не интуитивный результат, а именно:

- изменения первого слоя `major` типа `major.pop()` не изменяют передаваемый массив
- изменения второго слоя `major` типа `major[i].pop()` изменяют вложенные массивы передаваемого массива

из за этого после `minor(0,[[1,2],[3,4]])` не удаляется нулевая строка, но удаляется нулевой элемент первой строки, и в итоге передаваемый массив превращается в `[[1,2],[4]]` и далее возникает ошибка.

Тривиальным на мой взгляд является замена копии исходного массива на массив с копиями вложенных массивов: `major=[x.copy() for x in m]`:

```
def determinant(matrix):
    
    def minor(i,m):
        major=[x.copy() for x in m]
        major.pop(0)
        
        for row in major:
            row.pop(i)
            
        return major

    if len(matrix)==1:
        return matrix[0][0]
    
    sum=0
    
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        sum+=((-1)**j)*matrix[0][j]*determinant(minor(j,matrix))
        
    return sum
```

Однако работая с большими вложенностями, уместнее использовать указанную @CrazyElf библиотеку `from copy import deepcopy`

Answer (score 0):

Так происходит, потому что на первой же итерации `def minor(i,m):` возвращает `major`, а `major` при этом равен `Minor:  [[5]]` из ваших же логов. Далее вы вызываете `determinant` и передаёте результат `minor`, то есть `[[5]]`. После этого у вас `Matrix:  [[5]]`.

Решения можно придумать разные, но если вы хотите решать всё в функции `determinant`, вы не должны вызывать её рекурсивно. Кроме данной проблемы, у вас также каждый раз будет обнуляться `sum`.